# Why cURL outputs process name? And how to get rid of it?

Tags: bash, curl

Usually when you use cURL the output looks like that:

```
alex$ curl http://some-url
some-content
```

But, for some urls the outputs is different:

```
alex$ curl http://some-url
[1] 81030
alex$ some-content
[1]+  Done                    curl http://some-url
```

Why is that happening and how to get rid of it and make cURL to output just the content?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Kevin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38278158/45375) is helpful and Kevin deserves credit for inferring your specific problem in the absence of specific information.

Let me complement it with **general recommendations:**

Rather than *individually* escaping shell metacharacters (characters with special meaning to the shell) by `\`-prefixing them, consider:

- **enclosing *literals* in *single* quotes**; e.g.: `curl 'http://example.org/search&query=foo'`
- **enclosing *variable references* in *double* quotes**; e.g.: `url='http://example.org/search&query=foo'; curl "$url"`

That way you needn't worry about what individual characters to escape.

Generally, **only use *unquoted* literals / variable references if you explicitly *want* the the shell to interpret them** (by applying so-called [shell expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Expansions.html)).

Answer (score 6):

if some-url contains `&` character then shell interprets it as command to run the process in background.

To overcome it one can escape `&` with `\&` (prepend backslash).